# How can i change the blue radiance effect of IOS map to a custom effect?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mkmapview

How can i add a custom ring effect around the blue dot. I need the rippling effect of the ring around the blue do to repeat quicker and its colour to be changed to red. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/013GV.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change that without using some hackish technique. But try the tintColor of the mapView.
If that does not work, try to use this library:
https://github.com/TransitApp/SVPulsingAnnotationView

Comment: Well i already knew about this lib. But this doesn't help with repeating the rings to appear faster and with more intensity. Anyways thank you.

Comment: If changing the properties annotationColor, pulseAnimationDuration & outerPulseAnimationDuration of SVPulsingAnnotationView doesn't help you , I think you have to explain exactly what is missing